# android хранение в бд изображения

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, firebase

Написал приложение которое обрезает видео на изображение. Теперь думаю куда мне сохранять изображение. Так как бывает, что может получится больше 1к изображений,на память телефона нет смысла сохранять по понятным причинам, думаю исп. SQLiteManager
но не знаю сможет ли он хранить в себе такой большой объем 1к изображений, может какое то облачное хранилище? Подскажите, как лучше будет, что использова и где хранить?Может Firebase?

Comment: [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) может хранить терабайты данных.

Answer (score 1):

> ...на память телефона нет смысла сохранять по понятным причинам.

Почему вы думаете что хранение таких размеров файлов в БД это лучше?

Хранить изображения в БД не лучшая идея (хранение blob'a довольно трудоемкий процесс). Лучшим выходом будет использование файловой системы а пути к изображениям можно хранить в БД. 
Также для загрузки, хранения и отображения изображений с файловой системы можете использовать `Picasso`.

Answer (score 0):

Если не хотите или не видите смыла хранить на телефоне, тогда, из бесплатных до определённого уровня, подойдёт Firebase. Еслди изображения будут храниться только в течении сессии, то пишите на флэшку или в телефон, а ссылки храните в базе. Для работы с базой советую библиотеку Room.